# Axios request working fine by itself but when I try to integrate it with my discord bot it always returns an error?

Tags: node.js, api, axios, discord.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const axios = require("axios")
const { XRapidAPIKey, XRapidAPIHost} = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('stock')
        .setDescription('Replies with the name of the stock and its current price.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('ticker')
                .setDescription('The stock you want the price of.')
                .setRequired(true)),
                
        
    async execute(interaction) {
        const ticker = interaction.options.getString('ticker');
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://realstonks.p.rapidapi.com/${ticker.toUpperCase()}`,
            headers: {
                "X-RapidAPI-Key": XRapidAPIKey,
                "X-RapidAPI-Host": XRapidAPIHost
            }
            };
        
        
            axios.request(options).then(function(response) {   
                interaction.reply(response.data);                
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

this is the code for the stock price command but it does not work due to an error being thrown. It should send a message in my discord server with the json data from the axios request. It at first didn't work because I tried to put it in a function and return it but I realized that it needs to be in the command function but I cannot figure out why the request is returning a http 400 code even though it works fine by itself.

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/lukepitstick/personal/js/stocktrader/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/lukepitstick/personal/js/stocktrader/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async CommandInteraction.reply (/Users/lukepitstick/personal/js/stocktrader/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:103:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/986055380461301820/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTg2MDU1MzgwNDYxMzAxODIwOnY5c1QzbDdIWVN0NW4zY2d4ODd6M2RRSHA1OVpORHZ5SmFXUkNyY0pKZDNpNGNyVjFtQzZ5UjFYck96ZHhJUVlVNjJ6YWNHRTBFbFBSczlWWXBTdHk2YzFuNFJrRFU5R3R3dDAyQ3ByRmtiaTBpRm1NYUVyRXVHYjhsUk84T25t/callback',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

But when I run the code in its own file without the discord related stuff and console.log the data it outputs the json data as you would expect.

Comment: Notice how `data.content` is `undefined`.  That's probably the problem.  Did you do a `console.log(response.data)` to see exactly what you got back from your axios call?

Comment: Look for the `json list` of where you requesting the data, the do `response.data[0].the_name`, and you should do `console.log` aswell to see if it throw `undefined`

Comment: The error was actually that discord cannot send JSON files so I had to convert it to a string. Thanks for your help!